# UnwindSegue from View Controller containing a TableView back to Root View Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue, rootviewcontroller

How can I successfully unwind back to my Root View Controller? I am trying to use a button/nav bar item to return to previous Controller. I've seen a solution to use something like...

self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1

but I sadly could not make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Used the previous solution of...

@IBAction func goBackToController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
     self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2

}

and I forgot to set the initial View Controller to the tab controller!